# How to login with facebook in react?

Tags: reactjs, facebook, facebook-login

If I try to log in without publishing the application, the obstacle I encounter is "this application is still under development". If I try to launch the application and try to log in from my react application, the obstacle I encounter is "You will not be able to login with facebook until your application updates the security rules.". How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to login with `HTTP`, that's why you still got this error
you need to use `HTTPS` in dev-environment, try to install local SSL Certaficat Or use [Ngrock](https://ngrok.com/)
this article explains to you why this keep happening to you.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/06/08/enforce-https-facebook-login/

Comment: Should ı turn off  Enforce HTTPS
 ?

Comment: @MetehanKasap you can no longer turn it off you need to be on HTTPS in your localhost use `ngrock` for it

Comment: ı did setup ngrok and ı  wrote ./ngrok http 3000 and its gave me link. like https://fa22-5-27-27-255.ngrok.io now should ı paste this link of my faacebook app domain ?

Comment: @MetehanKasap yes or just write localhost

Comment: just "localhost" ?

Comment: @MetehanKasap yes

Comment: thank you,thats worked for me

Comment: You welcome :) @MetehanKasap